# Custom base path for Restler?

Tags: php, rest, restler

What's the recommended / supposed way to use a custom base path for Restler when it's not deployed at the root of a domain / subdomain?

My site has its own routing and I'm using [Restler](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler) 3.0 at here:

http://www.example.com/api/data/movies

When it routes to `/api/data/movies`, I'm letting Restler take charge:

```
class Say {
    function hello($to='world') {
        return "Hello $to!";
    }
    function hi($to) {
        return  "Hi $to!";
    }
}

use Luracast\Restler\Restler;
$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('Say', '/api/data/movies/say');
$r->handle();
```

However, somehow it's not getting the parameters passed to it via sub-path. See below.

### example.com/api/data/movies/say/hi

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Bad Request: `to` is required."
    },
    "debug": {
        "source": "Validator.php:366 at validate stage",
        "stages": {
            "success": [
                "get",
                "route",
                "negotiate"
            ],
            "failure": [
                "validate",
                "message"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### example.com/api/data/movies/say/hi/Jim

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
    },
    "debug": {
        "source": "Routes.php:431 at route stage",
        "stages": {
            "success": [
                "get"
            ],
            "failure": [
                "route",
                "negotiate",
                "message"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to Google but found nothing relevant to my problem. How can I make it work? What's the recommended / supposed way to use Restler under a sub-directory-URL instead of a domain / sub-domain root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Restler Documentation

You must have to pass `to` parameter in your URL Request, So I think your URL should be `example.com/api/data/movies/say/hi?to=test`.

But If you want to add custom Routing then Check how [Restler Routing Works](http://restler3.luracast.com/examples/_006_routing/readme.html).

> This API Server exposes the following URIs
>
> GET say/hi/{to} ⇠ Say::hi()

I am not familiar with Restler, But I hope this should be help for you.

Comment: Why does it say "required primitive types will be mapped to url path" [here](http://restler3.luracast.com/examples/_006_routing/readme.html)?

Answer (score 1):

With auto routing required primitive types used to be mapped to url path, this behaviour changed in the recent releases. Sorry about the confusion, we updated the documentation now!